# Hosts file filled with random URL links

Tags: hosts-file

I've just opened my hosts file on a remote computer in our house and found it filled with random URL's to other websites. Is this normal? I don't think it is meant to be filled with all these links and make me worried that these sites have gained access to the file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you post some of it in your question?  Malware sometimes uses the hosts file to redirect popular sites to phishing sites made to look the same.

Comment: Can you provide a few of the entries?  If they're all pointing to 127.0.0.1 it may be something you've installed to help block known bad sites....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what sort of URIs are in there, it could be anything from an ad-block to a malicious spyware that's inserting them in there.

If it was done without your knowledge then it is most definitely not normal. The original `hosts` file in Windows will only contain the localhost entry.

There are also certain "keygens" and software cracks that will insert entries into the `hosts` file, typically to prevent target applications from reaching their software activation servers.

If the entries in there are pointing to anything other than the loopback interface at `127.0.0.1`, then they are most likely malicious.

As noted by others, we won't know for sure unless you provide a sample of the entries.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I think it is malware. During the course of the year I install a lot of software and every year I clean everything off and start fresh so that the machine runs fast again. Any suggestions to good malware sofwtare?

Comment: @SixfootJames: I think Spybot S&D would have stopped the problem you had.